# Connecting to MS SQL database with Java JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have been working on this for quite a while and can't seem to get anything to work. Any time I try to connect to the database I get the following error if I don't try to reference a driver:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>   found for
>   jdbc:sqlserver://*******;databaseName=******;user=*********;password=*******

And the following error if I try to reference the Microsoft JDBC driver:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I've tried any suggestion for fixing this problem that I have been able to find. I've tried changing the classpath, including the driver JAR in the project somehow (if I even tried this correctly), and any other suggestions I could find.

Is there anything else I can try?

Code for reference, even though I don't think it is the problem:

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://*******;databaseName=*******;user=********;password=********");
    System.out.println("test");
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
    String Sql = "SELECT region_name FROM Region WHERE region_no=2";
    ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
```

Comment: Apparently the driver's jar file is not on your classpath.

Comment: My classpath is set to .;C:\Users\RS701554\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\sqljdbc.jar, which is the correct location of the sqljdbc jar.

Comment: The  `ClassNotFoundException` is a clear indication that whatever you did does not work for the IDE you are using. How did you specify this classpath? Which IDE are you using? How is your Java project configured in that IDE? If you are not using an IDE, then show us exactly how you run your Java code.

Comment: I think I fixed it. I am using IntelliJ right now, and I had to add the sqljdbc jar as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IntelliJ, adding sqljdbc4.jar as a dependency seems to have solved my issue.